# Android - Positioning an image at exact location

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, position

I am trying to position an image in my android app so that it will display in the middle of the width of screen and lower part of the height of the screen. I need it to look like this.

[image]

My image is 200x50, so I used following logic to achieve this.

```
Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
screenWidth = display.getWidth();
screenHeight = display.getHeight();
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play), screenWidth/2 - 100, 3*screenHeight/4 - 25, null);
```

But still I am not getting located at correct place and I am getting it like this.

[image]

What I am doing wrong here? How can I do this?

Comment: have look at the examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view

Comment: how do you want to set image via code or xml?

Comment: I prefer to do it in java for now since that what I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
screenWidth = display.getWidth();
screenHeight = display.getHeight();
Bitmap playImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play);
canvas.drawBitmap(playImage, (screenWidth/2) - (playImage.getWidth()/2), 3*screenHeight/4 - 25, null);
```

Comment: That's what I have done, isn't it? playImage.getWidth()/2 is 100.

Comment: Can you try to print playImage.getWidth()/2? Is it really coming as 100?

Comment: It worked and playImage.getWidth()/2 is 262, not 100, what is the reason for that?

Comment: With the screen density ratio the image dimension might vary

Answer (score 0):

why there is an need to write java code for this ?

just specify properties from xml.

```
center horizontal = true and margin bottom = "some value"
```

its done

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to this, I don't have an xml file like you have mentioned, I created a GamePanle object extending SurfaceView and added the code I mentioned there. Where should I add an xml code to do this and how should I refer to it?

Comment: Its definitely not 'done'. Not with `margin_bottom` above, mainly because most `ViewGroup` classes align their children to top-left

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna - Also keep in mind that you can achieve programmatically what you can in XML ... I'd suggest attempting use of XML for layout in most cases for style and separating view from logic as much as possible.

In code, I believe "center horizontal" is related to "gravity" on layout items, and margins should be available on most (if not all) widgets and views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alignParentBottom - true
centerHorizontal - true
marginBottom (Calculate 15% of height and set it)
```

Comment: Hi, I don't get this, should I do this in java code?

Comment: Try to set the same using `LayoutParams`

Comment: Just google it, eg link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678785/android-setting-layoutparams-programmatically